# Second order stochastic dominance characteristic

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

If x is Second Order stochastic dominant(SSD) to y, then it is equivalent to state that

$r_x + \epsilon = r_y $ with $E[e|r_x] \le 0 $

Proof: $E(U(1+r_y) = E[U(1+r_x+e)] 
= E[E[U(1+r_x +e)|r_x]] 
\le E[U(1+r_x +E[e|r_x]] \le E[U(1+r_x]$

My question is how $E[U(1+r_x+e)]$ change into $= E[E[U(1+r_x +e)|r_x]] $. Need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **every** random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ such that $\xi$ is integrable, $E[\xi]=E[E[\xi\mid\eta]]$. This is sometimes called the tower property, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Iterated_expectation).

Comment: ?? Did you read the link in my answer?